# how to shorten urls in javascript like how adf.ly does it

Tags: javascript, url, url-shortener

how can shorten urls using javascript into short unique strings. I tried using the algorithm from hashids.org but has not been successful. how do i do this?

Comment: This would make no sense, as the result of the shortening will have to be stored somewhere server-side for this to work.

Comment: Agree with Pekka. Generate the id, then store the unique mapping id in the database for example.

Comment: Ok, that will be the way to go then. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to make a proper, usable URL shortening with JavaScript.

How adf.ly does it, is they have a database backend, and with a server-side programming language (like PHP), they generate a unique hash, and then they store a record into the database, with that url, and that hash.

Then, when someone accesses that shortened URL, the system retrieves that result from the database by searching for that shortened portion, then redirects to that URL.

**Update:** If you really wanted to do it with JavaScript, there is a way:

Copy over [this function from PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/functions/base64_encode/), and then write something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="urlhere" />
<input type="button" onclick="shorten();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function shorten() {
    var shortened = base64_encode(document.getElementById("urlhere").value);
        document.getElementById("urlhere").value = "http://www.example.com/shortened/" + encodeURIComponent(shortened);
  }
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HusuX/)

And on the redirected page, parse the URL with JavaScript, get that portion of the URL, decode the URL, then redirect to that URL.

It's definitely not a good method. Trust me. No one likes typing a base64 string, and no one wants to copy it.

Comment: @user3183103 No worries.